# Thin font not showing correctly on windows

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome, font-face

I am trying to use "HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight" on my website. On OSX, it looks perfect in every browser. On Windows, it's horrible:

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

IE:
[image]

I am using the following CSS (if it matters):

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight';
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.ttf');
}


body{font-family:'HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight'; font-weight:normal;}

/*** IE FONT ***/
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight';
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight.svg#HelveticaNeueLTStd25UltraLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;}
```

Can someone explain why this is? What can I do about it? If I must use another font, which fonts are safe to use?

Comment: You need to use a font with better anti-aliasing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows just has crappier font rendering in browsers than OSX or iOS does.  Sometimes you can fix it by picking specific font sizes at which the browser antialiasing doesn't look too awful.  There is also the `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` CSS property but in my experience it often does more harm than good.

Pick a different font that is more optimized for web display.  [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) is a good place to start.  They have lots of great modern fonts that are all optimized to be used as webfonts, and on top of that they provide the CSS etc - you just need to `<link>` to their external CDN CSS file in your `<head>` and bam you're good to go. "Lato" and "Raleway" are fonts I use in place of Helvetica Neue sometimes.

Also, it's **almost certainly** illegal to embed that font anyway since Helvetica Neue LT Std is a commercial font, so...

Comment: Thanks you! Looks like I need to use a different font anyway, I don't even remember where I got the font from if it's commercial. I will check out the 2 fonts you suggested.

Comment: No problem.  Helvetica and Helvetica Neue are really popular in the design world so this is not an unheard-of issue!  If you google "Helvetica Neue webfont alternatives" you will find dozens of suggestions.  Thanks for marking this the answer :)

Comment: For anyone else looking for an alternative: I ended up going with Roboto 100 from Google Web Fonts. Very thing but still looks much better on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser renders fonts differently using different methods that is why you are including so many different versions of the font, as each is used by a different browsers. OSX has one of the best font rendering engines, things look great, but look at in IE or FF or Chrome and things tend to be different. There isn't much you can do apart from trying a font that is a bit thicker.

You can see maybe if maybe `font-weight: 500` helps.